# Create reset button for number guessing game

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a number guessing game for a tutorial in Python. I'm new to Python and using Python Shell and version 2.7.5. I've made all the functions besides this one.

I have to make a reset button and that is messing with my mind. I have no clue how to define it.

```
self.reset_bttn = Button(self, text = "Starta om", command=reset)
        self.reset_bttn.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)

def reset():
        global
```

This is the beginning of the code with some of the labels.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
number = random.randrange (100) + 1
tries = 0
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):

        self.inst_lbl = Label(self, text = "Följ alla stegen")
        self.inst_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        self.name_lbl = Label(self, text = "Spelarens namn: ")
        self.name_lbl.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.name_ent = Entry(self)
        self.name_ent.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.guess_lbl = Label(self, text = "Skriv in din gissning.")
        self.guess_lbl.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.guess_ent = Entry(self)
        self.guess_ent.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.gap1_lbl = Label(self, text = " ")
        self.gap1_lbl.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to add the following to your Application class:

```
class Application(Frame):
    # ... all the stuff you've copied in your question
    def create_widgets(self):
        # ... all the stuff again
        self.reset_bttn = Button(self, text = "Starta om", command=self.reset)

    def reset(self):
        self.name_ent.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.guess_ent.delete(0, tk.END)
        # ... more stuff to be reset here
```

I did not test this, and never have done `tkinter` (at least as far as I remember), but I just read the [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html)! ;-)

> .delete(first, last=None)
>     Deletes characters from the widget, starting with the one at index first, up to but not including the character at position last. If the second argument is omitted, only the single character at position first is deleted.

and:

> Positions within the widget's displayed text are given as an index. There are several ways to specify an index:
>
> - As normal Python indexes, starting from 0.
> - The constant tk.END refers to the position after the existing text.

oh, I feel the need to add that you shall **NEVER EVER** use globals. There is no good reason or situation to use them. Except if you want to make an ugly code that's hard to read and maintain.

you should instead be pushing those global variables inside the class as members.

Answer (score 0):

- Moved global variables to instance attribute. (`number`, `tries`).
- Reset text entry by calling .delete(0, END).

---

```
# coding: utf-8

from Tkinter import *
import random

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.reset()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.inst_lbl = Label(self, text = "Följ alla stegen")
        self.inst_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

        self.name_lbl = Label(self, text="Spelarens namn: ")
        self.name_lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.name_ent = Entry(self)
        self.name_ent.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.guess_lbl = Label(self, text="Skriv in din gissning.")
        self.guess_lbl.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.guess_ent = Entry(self)
        self.guess_ent.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.reset_bttn = Button(self, text="Starta om", command=self.reset)
        self.reset_bttn.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

    def reset(self):
        self.number = random.randint(1, 100)
        self.tries = 0
        self.name_ent.delete(0, END)
        self.guess_ent.delete(0, END)

root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanx! but if I where to delete more labels what do I do? I would like the reset button to reset all parameters visible in the window. Below is the reveal statement used on the guess btn
`def reveal(self):
        global tries
        name = self.name_ent.get()
        guess = self.guess_ent.get()
        if int(guess) > int(number):
            result_msg = "Tyvärr det är lägre!!"
            tries += 1
        if int(guess) < int(number):
            result_msg = "Tyvärr det är högre!!"
            tries += 1
        if int(guess) == int(number):
            result_msg `code`

Comment: Your answer isn't very useful without a description. Can you please take the time to describe what you did and why?

Comment: @BryanOakley, added description. Sorry for poor English.

Comment: @BryanOakley I was making a number guessings game for a laboration in a python course. It's pretty long code, but the main thing is I need to have a close window buton and a reset button, the reset button works after the answer from, But I wish to add more things to reset when I press reset. For example the amount of tries, and the messages show to the user, basically ALL information in the window to be remowed/reseted.

Comment: @andrejcurcic: if this is for a class, you shouldn't be asking people how to do it, you should figure it out for yourself. Everything you need to know is in documentation readily available on the internet.

Comment: @andrejcurcic, code you put in comment is hard to read. Please update question or post another question.